# Nagios php script to read iostat values

Tags: php, scripting, nagios, awk, iostat

I'm working on a php script(nagios plugin) to read `r/s,w/s,rMB/s,wMB/s,%util` from the iostat command, e.g.

```
#iostat -xm sda
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.05    0.08    1.16    6.24    0.00   91.47

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s    %util
sda               0.14    10.37    3.63    2.31     0.06     0.05    1.53
```

Any ideas how I can filter `r/s,w/s,rMB/s,wMB/s and %util` values using awk or if there is another way to run commands within a php script?

Comment: Instead of trying to parse the output of a command, maybe parse the contents of `/proc/diskstats`, `/proc/uptime`, `/proc/stat`,  which is iostat seems to read from.  See the kernel docs/source for details for the format of these state files.

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing your own plugin, instead of using an existing one?

Comment: @Keith , company standards sadly, php environment